# How to get the phase/angle from an Alglib complex variable

Tags: fft, dft, phase, stft, complex

It is easy to get the magnitude using alglib.abscomplex function (https://radfiz.org.ua/files/temp/Lab1_16/alglib-3.4.0.csharp/csharp/manual.csharp.html#gs_stdfunctions), but I would like to know, how to get the phase information from a complex variable. Please tell me, if you know a good solution, thanks!

Comment: It's all trigonemetry. Look at what the arcustangens does to the quota of real and imaginary part.

Comment: But how can I get the real and imaginary part from the Alglib complex variable?

Comment: the alglib docs you link to actually explain that: `.x` and `.y`.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry I just did not see that